# db4o's store and commit usage scenario

Tags: db4o

I found call store without commit or call commit without store both can write data into disk. In my opinion, store is used to update object in container or put new created obj into container. commit do the disk write job.

I have not use TP & TA, I set enough updateDepth & minimumActivationDepth level. I observed that when I call store(obj), there are java.io.RandomAccessFile methods called. Data should be written into disk.

So what is the purpose to make 2 functions: store and commit? Why not just make a single api, say: save() ?

Comment: Because you may want to make a set of objects accessible at once (transactional behavior) and the process of storing may take place at different code place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods have two distinct tasks:

Store(): Tell db4o that you want to store / update this object. However this only enlists the changes to the transaction.

Commit(): Make all changes permanent and start a new transaction. Without the commit call the Store method will have no effect. (Note that .commit is implicitly called by close/dispose).
In case you think a mistake happen or on a error you can call .Rollback instead to undo all your changes.

You can read more about transactions on the net, tons of examples around.

This is nothing special and many databases use this kind of semantics. Almost all SQL, Object and other databases.

Comment: why only commit without store can also store the changes of data?

Comment: Without store the commit operation will do nothing. Store() adds the changes which you wanna make to the transaction. Commit() persists the changes listed in the transaction. When the Commit() call succeeds, everything is on disk. Before that, no permanent changes are made.

Comment: I test this in db4o 8.0, jdk6, open a object container, get a object from database, change it data member, then commit (without store). Query it again and see the data member, it is updated value. Or, close db after commit. Check the value in db by OME, it is updated value. You can try it. The only flaw is: you can not query the changed data member, that will be old data. You need to query the root object.(I think because of object container's cache)

Comment: When your using Transparent persistence, this is the case. Otherwise not and you have a hidden store somewhere. Except of course that you get the cached object back with the most current value.